# Determining if any divs are hidden in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radtreeview

I have a RadTreeView with a custom NodeTemplate. Inside that node template, I have the node surrounded in a `div`, like so:

```
<div id="divCommandRow">
    <!-- My template goes here -->
</div>
```

After the RadTreeView renders, my DOM has several `<div id="divCommandRow">` divs in the DOM. My question is, how can I use jQuery to query if any of these div's have `display: none` style? I created the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    function IsInEditMode() {
        $('#divCommandRow').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':visible'))
                return true;
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: IDs must be _unique_. Your selector `$('#divCommandRow')` only selects the first matched element with ID of `divCommandRow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('selector').length == $('selector:visible').length
```

or

```
$('selector:not(:visible)').length == 0
```

With this condition you check if all the elements that match `selector` selector are visible